# Detailed proof that $\circ_i$ operads are the same as operads

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, operads

The original definition of operads involves maps
$$ \gamma\colon C(n) \times \prod_{i=1}^n C(k_i) \to C(\sum_ik_i) $$ 
There is an alternative definition in terms of maps
$$ \circ_i \colon C(n) \times C(m) \to C(n+m-1). $$
It is not hard to outline an argument that the two definitions are equivalent (subject to some assumptions about $C(0)$ and $C(1)$; various choices of details are possible).  Have the details been spelled out carefully somewhere?  I have seen this called an "observation", but that seems a little blasé to me.

Comment: I've seen it in the Ginzburg & Kapranov [Koszul duality paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1228v1.pdf). Not making this an answer since I am not sure what is your rigor standard :D (The paper has a subsequent [erratum](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077245862#ui-tabs-1) but it concerns a different place)

Comment: Phil Hackney just mentioned that they are not equivalent if $C(1)$ is not the unit of the monoidal structure. Maybe that is relevant?

Comment: @SeanTilson you are right that this is an issue; I have added a parenthetical comment.

Comment: I put a proof in one of my papers, but the referee told me to take it out.

Comment: @GregoryArone If you still have the draft of that paper you could copy-paste that proof here as an answer and finally get it out in the open. (A reference to a MO post is better than nothing...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a detailed discussion of the "partial" composition operations of an operad in Volume 1, Chapter 2 of Fresse's monograph:

- Benoit Fresse, *Homotopy of Operads & Grothendieck-Teichmüller Groups*. ([book project web page](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/)) ([author pdf for volume 1](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/OperadHomotopy-FirstVolume.pdf))

The equivalence of the two definitions of operad is stated as Theorem 2.1.10, and the proof is worked out in Appendix A (see A.2.10).